# A class that can parse IP domain (e.g. 192.168.0.0/16)

Tags: d, phobos

I am writing a simple script in D that needs to interface with command-line network programs that use IP domain addresses (e.g. `10.0.14.0/24`).

Is there any ready parser existing for that in D?

Something, that can validate a domain and break it into elements.

Comment: the vocab word you're looking for is "CIDR notation". and I know I've written this before but idk if I still have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug up my old code and formatted it a bit for github. It is probably buggy though:

https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/blob/master/cidr.d

You use it like

```
import cidr;
import std.stdio;
void main() {
     auto block = IPv4Block("192.168.1.0/24");
     foreach(address; block) writeln(address);
}
```

and stuff like that.

Comment: Thank you!! I hope one day I will contribute some nice libraries back to the community!